# Is Out-Host buffering?

Tags: powershell

I ha a function, where I call an application with the `&` operator. The application produces several line command line output, downloads some files, and returns a string:

```
& "app.exe" | Out-Host
$var = ...
return $var
```

It seems, that on the console appears the output produced by `app.exe` only after `app.exe` terminates. The user does not have any real time information which file is downloading. Is there a way to continuously update the console when `app.exe` is running?

Comment: What if you run `"app.exe" | more` in CMD, does it show results immediately then?

Comment: Will `more` send output to the standard output? I am using `Write-Host` to prevent output data being captured in the returned variable.

Comment: PowerShell pipeline doesn't work like cmd for external utilities. It indeed waits for the command to complete. Simply invoke `app.exe` without `&` and `out-host`.

Comment: I am using `&` because the path to `app.exe` is in a variable, so I am invoking it using a string.

Comment: `& { & "app.exe" } | Out-Default`

Comment: @PetSerAl it is working. Can you explain your solution?

Comment: @Robert Can you answer my first question, so I can confirm my guess?

Comment: @PetSerAl, the variant using `more` does not show the result immediately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many console applications buffer theirs output stream, if it known to be redirected. Actually, [it is standard behavior of C library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31174617). So, buffering is done on `app.exe`, because of redirection, but not by `Out-Host`.

A solution would be to not to redirect the output of `app.exe`, even when the outer command redirected. For than you should know the [exact](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master@%7B2016-11-08%7D/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/NativeCommandProcessor.cs#L1124) condition when PowerShell does **not** redirect output stream of console application and, link it directly to their own output stream, which would be a console for interactive `PowerShell.exe` session. The conditions is:

1. Command is last item in pipeline.
2. Command is piped to `Out-Default`.

Solution would be wrap command into script block, and pipe that script block to `Out-Default`:

```
& { & "app.exe" } | Out-Default
```

The other solution would be to use `Start-Process` cmdlet with `-NoNewWindow` and `-Wait` parameters:

```
Start-Process "app.exe" -NoNewWindow -Wait
```